# How to update my loging/logout links after Facebook logout

Tags: ajax, facebook-graph-api, session-variables, authentication

I am working an a test page to get the Facebook login button functionality correct.

I got the FB button to work correctly when the person logs in and logs out of FB.  But I am not sure how to get my sites' header to update to toggle the login/logout link.

After the FB loging/logout I update the site's session with all the same data as I would during regular login/logout, but for some reason the header does not update there.

Any idea how to fix it?  FYI I am testing this stuff out here: http://www.comehike.com/test_fb_connect.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, for that you would have to use Facebook's Javascript API to detect when the user has logged in or logged out, and then do an AJAX request for updating your header. This would be done through FB.Event.subscribe, as the following snippet points out:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
        appId  : 'YOURAPPID',
        status : true, // check login status
        cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
        xfbml  : true,  // parse XFBML
        channelUrl  : 'http://www.yourdomain.com/channel.html', // Custom Channel URL
        oauth : true //enables OAuth 2.0
    });

    // retrieve the login status.
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
        if (response.authResponse) update_user_is_connected();
        else update_user_is_not_connected();
    });

    // This will be triggered as soon as the user logs into Facebook (through your site)
    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
        // Here you would update your header.
        update_user_is_connected();
    });
};
```

You can read more about FB.Event.subscribe here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/

Please note this code is taken from [previous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6874718/facebook-oauth2-0-implementation/6875208#6875208) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6885274/post-to-facebook-how-to-get-responce-without-refreshing/6885459#6885459) of mine.

Comment: I am already doing all that, and sending an AJAX call to log the person in and out.  Just the general site, for some reason, doesn't reflect that.

Comment: if you look at the link I posted, no matter if you log in or out of fb, the ajax calls I make to update the generall user session on the site, do not reflect the login/logout link on top right.

Comment: Yes, this is clearly because you are not checking (in your PHP) whether the user is logged in or not. This can be done through getUser();

Comment: you mean at the top of the page?  Which getUser function are you referring to? I am confused.

Comment: Yeah, I mean at the top of the page. Facebook's PHP API has got a function called getUser(). This function will return 0 if the user is not logged in or the user ID if it is. Still, I've found some quite strange behaviors when mixing FB tags and their PHP SDK (like, the button says you're logged in, but the PHP says otherwise). Thus, I'd recommend using Facebook SDK's GetLoginUrl() for retrieving a valid URI, rather than using their button.

Comment: I think maybe you don't understand my question.  I was updating my site's session already.  I don't need to call the Facebook method to see if the user is logged in.  What I need is to have the login/logout link toggle after the AJAX runs to login/logout the user after they use the fb button.  Does that make sense?

Comment: Hm, well, now that I do understand, you should do that through AJAX the following way: using the FB.Event.subscribe in my answer, update your div.site_login with valid information (this would be JS for instant changing of it, I'd use jQuery). Any other changes should be done directly on your PHP.

Comment: @JulianBayardoSpadafora let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2106/discussion-between-genadinik-and-julian-bayardo-spadafora)